# [PWA Studio][BUG] Page Builder column-line content type is not supported, this content will not be rendered

Tags: pwa-studio, page-builder, venia, magento2.4.5

Ever since we upgraded to Magento 2.4.5 our Pagebuilder content that uses a column has stopped working. We tested this on a clean Pwa Studio install with a Magento 2.4.5 backend attached to it.

I have added this issue on the PWA studio github for a more detailed description: https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/issues/3949

Comment: Do you find the solution?